# Input width auto (autoresized based on content length)

Tags: css, input, width

I'm trying to make an input autoresize to fit content (not bigger or smaller than needed)

```css
form {
  white-space:nowrap;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin:10px;
  padding: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
}

input, button {
  display:inline-block;
}

input {
  max-width: none;
  min-width: 0;
  width: auto;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button>-</button>
  <input type="text" value="0"> minutes
  <button>+</button>
</form>

<form>
  <button>-</button>
  <input type="text" value="500"> minutes
  <button>+</button>
</form>
```

But width `auto` doesn't do the trick, at least in firefox,

Any idea why?

Comment: i think this width is the minimum we got when we use `input` tag

Comment: So noworkaround with css only?

Comment: You can use size attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/p3cwwvow/ ?

Comment: @nevermind i see, the problem is that this way they don't resize either, its like setting a fixed width.. http://jsfiddle.net/p3cwwvow/3/

Comment: Yes, however, i am 99% sure that pure css solution is not possible in this case, you will need javascript, if you want automatic resizing related to content....

Answer (score 0):

Well,

As I don't see a css only solution, this a solution involving javascript

(but refering the original question, I would like not to use js if posible..)

```js
$('input').on('change keyup', function() {
  var fontsize = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
  var value = $(this).val();
  var length = value.length;
  $(this).width(fontsize*length))
});
```

```css
form {
  white-space:nowrap;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin:10px;
  padding: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
}

input, button {
  display:inline-block;
}

input {
    width: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button>-</button>
  <input type="text" value="0"> minutes
  <button>+</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you a live example?

This should be able to be done with CSS and not using JS but would need to be able to check the rest of the code to see that this would fit and work correctly

Comment: Yes click on the snippet of the question "Run code snippet" bue button

Comment: This should be a comment, by the way, not an answer (yet..)